# Android - RecyclerView - items positions issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

i have one activity that contains on RecyclerView.
to insert a new item, there are a custom dialog that contains on two editText and one spinner used to get some information required from user and then returns this information back and displayed it in recyclerView
see the image

[image]

this is the custom dialog witch i used to insert new item,
if you see the number of each item , there is no problem until now.

[image]

when the soft input appears(keyboard), then there are some thing happen on the items, the positions of some of them are changed

[image]

see the positions of the last items !

it is changed

[image]

the cancel button on the dialog does nothing,

this is the recycleView after dismiss the custom dialog

[image]

i think the problem is happen because the recycling feature.

adapter used for recyclerView :

```
private class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>
{
    private View courseView;
    private TextView courseNo;
    private TextView courseName ;
    private TextView courseHours;
    private TextView courseGrades;

    protected class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            courseView = itemView;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        courseView = LayoutInflater
                .from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_course,parent,false);

        courseNo = (TextView)courseView.findViewById(R.id.view_course_textView_no);
        courseName = (TextView)courseView.findViewById(R.id.view_course_textView_name);
        courseHours = (TextView)courseView.findViewById(R.id.view_course_textView_hours_value);
        courseGrades = (TextView)courseView.findViewById(R.id.view_course_textView_grade_value);

        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(courseView);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final int coursePosition = position;
        courseNo.setText(position+1+"");
        courseName.setText(courses.get(position).getName());
        courseHours.setText(courses.get(position).getHours()+"");
        courseGrades.setText(courses.get(position).getGrade()+"");

        courseView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                editDialog(coursePosition);
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return courses.size();
    }
}
```

where **courses** is List of items

Comment: Can you post here your code for the Adapter? Your problem is probably in binding ViewHolder

Comment: @VarvaraKalinina ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are implementing Adapter wrong.

Consider this example of a ViewHolder:

```
class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        protected ImageView imageView;
        protected TextView textView;

        public CustomViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            this.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            this.textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        }
    }
```

View variables must be fields of the ViewHolder, not the Adapter. In your case

```
private View courseView;
private TextView courseNo;
private TextView courseName ;
private TextView courseHours;
private TextView courseGrades;
```

must be fields of the ViewHolder, not the Adapter.

Setting `onClickListener` must go inside `onCreateViewHolder()`, not `onBindViewHolder()`, or you'll end up with multiple repeating onClickListeners for the same item.

And I don't think you need to keep a reference to `View courseView` at all.